# Depth Strider without boots

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is there a way to give a player Depth Strider III effect without using boots or armor? I'm setting something up on a public server (1.9), and I don't want to automatically/accidentally override any armor boots, etc, that they might have on. Can I use a command block to give them the effect? Speed doesn't seem to work under water, I've noticed.

Comment: I don't think it's possible. As a workaround, you could detect whether or not someone has boots equipped and notify them to take them off.

Comment: Not really a solution, but you could edit the `ench` tag if the player drops their boots on the ground or puts them in a specific inventory.

Comment: In theory, would either equipping them with depth strider boots if they're not wearing any, or adding/removing the depth strider effect to existing boots work when they're in the spawn area?

Comment: @theBeaks I don't see why not. You can use one command block to detect if they are in a certain radius, and apply a command. If that isn't the case, a second command bock can remove that effect (if it has been applied)

Comment: You can use chain armor with NBT data that nobady else can get on your server. Like change it's name to something nobody would think of

Comment: I was thinking as a solution of giving new players on the server a set of cheap armor, with depth strider 3 on the boots, and then having a Need Boots? sort of spot that would /give players boots with a ProprtyOfSpawn sort of name. Then, maybe once every so often remove all PropertyOfSpawn boots from players inventories when they're not at spawn. Not sure if that would be a huge lag issue, though. If there are say 20 people online, and other command blocks running at spawn, do you think that might be super lag inducing?